# wp7 webbrowser control opening a centered image

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have been looking for a simple way to allow a similar functionality to the built-in Image Viewer (Zooming in and out of an image with 2 fingers, pinch zoom / zoom out, and the floating effect, if someone gently pushes an image in one of the directions).

Initially I was trying to achieve it with the Image control, but It turned out to be extremely difficult.

I decided to go with the Webbrowser control, as it seemed to offer just what I need and it had a benefit of clipping it's content to the parent container ( an Image control wouldn't do that by default ).

I placed the Webbrowser control in the second Row of a 2-row parent Grid container (Its basically the default Page generated by Visual Studio)

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" IsIndeterminate="True" />
            <phone:WebBrowser Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="BrowserWindow" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
</Grid>
```

The C# code backing the View is this:

public partial class ItemDetailView : PhoneApplicationPage
{

```
public static string HtmlTemplate =
    @"<!doctype html>
      <html>
        <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=0.1,minimum-scale=0.1,user-scalable=yes,width=480' />
        <title></title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function imageLoadFailed() {{
            window.external.notify('ImageLoadFailed');
        }}
        </script>
        </head>
        <body style='margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; background-color: {0};'>
        <div style='margin:0 auto;'><img onerror='imageLoadFailed()' src='{1}' alt='' /></div>
        </body>
      </html>";


public ItemDetailView() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BrowserWindow.LoadCompleted += (s, e) => {
        this.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
        this.BrowserWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    };

    this.BrowserWindow.ScriptNotify += (s, e) => {
        if (e.Value == "ImageLoadFailed") {
            MessageBox.Show("Image failed to load");
        }
    };
}

public ItemDetailViewModel VM {
    get {
        return this.DataContext as ItemDetailViewModel
    }
}

public bool IsBackgroundBlack() {
    return Visibility.Visible == (Visibility)Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"];
}
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    App app = App.Current as App;
    this.VM.Item = app.CurrentItem;

    string css = "";
    if (this.IsBackgroundBlack()) {
        css = "black";
    }
    else {
        css = "white";
    }
    this.BrowserWindow.NavigateToString(string.Format(ItemDetailView.HtmlTemplate, css, app.CurrentItem.Url));

}
```

}

As you may see, I set the width to 480 in the Viewport meta tag. This is the only value that is close enough to center the image so it appears naturally as if placed in an Image control (it fits within the width of the phones screen and is scaled appropriately)

I tried to set the viewport meta tag width property to 'device-width', but with this setting, the image reaches beyond the phones screen width upon initial load.

I also have noticed that with width set to 480, if a user taps on the Web browser for the first time, the browser centers the image a little bit, so 480 is not a perfect value. I am also concerned that this may not be the greatest solution given multiple screen sizes of other devices.

I am curious, if there is a cross-device way to center the image in the web browser control.

Reference Image:

[image]

- Left Image - What I want, and what it more or less looks like with Viewport meta tag's width=480 (Entire image is seen)
- Right Image - What it looks like with Viewport meta tag's width=device-width;
  (A single tap is needed to zoom out and position it in the center like the left image)

Comment: You could try using CSS to center the image (second example: http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate some CSS techniques. There's a problem though - most of them assume that I know upfront the size of the image. Here I don't. I probably could leverage JavaScript, but if that causes the image to 'jump' into the right position after page load, then it's a no-no. :(

Comment: Not sure what it would be like, but one way around that is to hide the WebBrowser control with another control ('loading screen' or something?) and then hide the new control when the WebBrowser has fully loaded. That way, you can do all the adjusting without the user knowing and only showing them the final result.

Comment: Hm, it's actually what I am doing already. Ok, in that case some JavaScript may not be that bad. I'll see what I can achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no need for setting the meta tag at all (it just caused trouble in my case)

the html template:

```
<!doctype html>
              <html>
                <head>
                <title></title>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                function imageLoadFailed() {
                    window.external.notify('ImageLoadFailed');
                }
                </script>
                </head>
                <body style='background-color: {0};'>
                <img width='100%' onerror='imageLoadFailed()' src='{1}' alt='' /></div>
                </body>
              </html>
```

does the trick